# Need Webinar bar to be equal to the image above...its two pixels short

Tags: html, css

I noticed my images are a couple pixels longer than the "Webinar" bar. How do I get the "Webinar" bar to be equal width to the images?

Here's my Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/0zfwf2dk/37/

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="resources-box">
    <div class="column-resources-box">
        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple"><img alt="Apples" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/apples.jpg" width="193" /></a>
        <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">WEBINAR</a></h4>
            <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">Apples</a></strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column-resources-box">
        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana"><img alt="Bananas" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/bananas.jpg" width="193" /></a>
        <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana">WEBINAR</a></h4>
            <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana">Bananas</a></strong></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column-resources-box">
        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange"><img alt="Orange" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/Oranges.jpg" width="193" /></a>
        <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange">WEBINAR</a></h4>
            <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange">Orange</a></strong></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column-resources-box">
        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple"><img alt="Pineapple" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/Pineapples.jpg" width="193" /></a>
        <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple">WEBINAR</a></h4>
            <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple">Pineapple</a></strong></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here's my CSS

```
.resources-box {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #e2e3e4;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.column-resources-box {
    width: 193px;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.column-resources-box img {
border: 1px solid #2251a4;
}

h4 {
font-family: Georgia,Helvetica,Arial;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 1em 0 .6em 0;
}

h4.resources-bar a {
font-family: Georgia;
font-size: 11px !important;
color: #ffffff !important;
background-color: #2251a4;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: block;
}

h4.resources-bar a:hover {
background-color: #f66511;
color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the borders around the images.

If you remove the `width` from the `column-resources-box` class they will match, since the other elements will not be restricted to `193px`

```
.column-resources-box {
   /* width: 193px;*/ /*commented this line*/
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/0zfwf2dk/38/

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can do to fix the width issue.  But one easy way to make sure borders and padding stay within the width you set for your elements is to change the box-sizing to border-box.  You can do it for your whole document.  So for instance if you add a 2px border to a 190px width box, the overall width of the box with the border will by default show in the browser as 194px (adding left and right borders) and any padding will add to that as well.  BUT if you use the border-box setting for box-sizing, the border and box and any padding will equal 190px.  You can do this for all your elements in your code to be consistent:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```